# Change frontpage content via Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started to work with Wordpress (Theme Development) and due to awesome functions like bloginfo('description') and others my static homepage looks a lot like a regular site, but editable with the Wordpress Dashboard.

But now, I want to put more information on my homepage which I can edit through the dashboard. I guess this is really basic Wordpress and that a simple Wordpress function or MySQL-query should be enough, but I can't seem to find it.

This is my code right now:

```
    <div class="fp-container">
    <div class="fp-border">
        <h1 class="fp-description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="fp-text">
        <p><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
    </div>
```

As you can see, between the '< p>' and '< /p>' I call the description for the second time, how can I call another string that can be entered through the Dashboard?

Rik

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<div class="fp-container">
<div class="fp-border">
    <h1 class="fp-description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h1>
</div>
<div class="fp-text">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: <?php the_content(); ?> is editable through page dashboard's editor.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. But if I want to add another text box, and another, and another. I can't use the_content() for that I guess?

Comment: You can use <?php the_content(); ?> only one time.